# Script an Executable Whose Path Changes with Updates

Tags: bash, path, cron, homebrew

I'm looking for a way to find `pg_dump` amongst updates that changes its path.  Here are two recent versions of `pg_dump` that mess with my `crontabs` for automated backups:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.6_2/bin/pg_dump
/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10/10.8/bin/pg_dump
```

When the script simply calls for `pg_dump`, it cannot found, so at a bare minimum, it has to be exported in the `$PATH` in the script itself.  Same problem.

Is there a way of sniffing where `pg_dump` is, at the time the script is run?

Is there a better way of getting this done while still using `pg_dump`?

BTW I'm using `Mac OS`, whose `realpath` doesn't seem to work.  It points to a fake `/Users/rich/pg_dump` which does not exist.

Just tried the following and the output to the log was empty:

```
c1=$(which pg_dump)
echo $c1
eval $c1
```

This works when run as my own user, but I'm uncertain as to who the user is for crontabs.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you need:

```
pg_dump_path=$(find -L '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10' -type f -name 'pg_dump' -printf '%T@\t%f\n' | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -f2-)

[[ -x "$pg_dump_path" ]] || {printf 'Failed to find pg_dump.\n' >&2; exit 1}

pg_dump_bin="${pg_dump_path%/*}"

echo "$pg_dump_bin"
echo "$pg_dump_path"
```

I'm piping to sort/head/cut to ensure you only get 1 result, the most recently installed version of the tool. If that's not all you need then update your question to clarify.

If your version of `find` doesn't support `-printf` then you can use:

```
-exec stat -f $'%a\t%N' {} \;
```

instead of:

```
-printf '%T@\t%f\n'
```

to get the timestamp and path to the file.

Comment: `find: -executable: unknown primary or operator`  I'm on El Capitan, so `find` might be updated recently.

Comment: Then just remove that test. It's not strictly necessary. I removed it from my answer.

Comment: `find: -executable: unknown primary or operator
/users/rich/RF/RF_scripts/crons/pg_neb_daily_backupto_Dragon2.sh: line 41: {printf: command not found
/users/rich/RF/RF_scripts/crons/pg_neb_daily_backupto_Dragon2.sh: line 41: exit: 1}: numeric argument required`

Comment: `pg_dump_path=$(find '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10' -type f -name 'pg_dump' -printf '%T@\t%f\n' | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -f2-)`

Comment: @Rich_F if your `find` doesn't support `-printf` then you can probably use `-exec stat {} \;` instead with some options for `stat` but if you can only find 1 version of `pg_dump` then you can just get rid of `-printf '%T@\t%f\n' | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -f2-`. Is that the case? If you can find multiple versions but don't care which one then you can replace that chain of commands with `| head -1`.

Comment: `find pg_dump` comes up with nothing.  Your reduced command also comes up with nothing.  `which pg_dump` comes up with a single entry.

Comment: If `find dir ... pg_dump` doesn't find `pg_dump` then `pg_dump` doesn't exist in `dir`. You provided the value for `dir` in your question. If that's the wrong place to look then don't look there, look in whatever the correct place is instead.

Comment: The dir is the correct place listed as '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10', but it is finding nothing.  Maybe my `find` is screwed.

Comment: That is **extremely** unlikely. Maybe there's some symbolic links that `find` isn't following. I added `-L` to the `find` in my answer to follow those if they're present.

Comment: `[/usr/local/Cellar] $  find -L '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10' -type f -name 'pg_dump'
find: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@10: unknown primary or operator`  Also, without `-L` returns nothing.

Comment: I can't imagine what version of `find` command you're running. That syntax is correct for find in bash 4.4.12 on MacOS Mojave (10.14.5). Yes, we had previously established that without `-L` it returns nothing, that's why we added the `-L`, to see if symlinks were the problem.

Comment: You'll just have to poke around at the `/usr/local/Cellar/` directory structure yourself using combinations of `find` and `ls -l` to figure out what's going on, I'm out of ideas without having access to your file system (and no, I don't want access to your file system!).

Comment: I'm on `bash 5.0.7(1)-release`.  Thanks all the same.  I've hard coded it for now.  Can I not use `which pg_dump` which works fine?

Comment: Didn't you ask this question because you `Just tried the following and the output to the log was empty:

c1=$(which pg_dump)`? If it works then yes, by all means use it. You're really going to want to figure out what's going on with your environment and tools at some point though - even if you can work around this one issue for now, whatever is going on with your tools/files/environment will bite you sooner or later.

Comment: It works with my login, but it doesn't seem to work from the crontab's user (I don't know who that is).  I just feel as if I'm fairly close.

Comment: It doesn't matter who the crontab user is (but you could put `whoami` or similar in a cron job to find out) - `which` just looks down your `PATH` for a command. If you do `which pg_dump` as yourself and it outputs `/foo/bar/bin/pg_dump` and then set `PATH="/foo/bar/bin:$PATH"` in your cron job then `which pg_dump` in your cron job will output the same thing. Alternatively you could just do `echo "$PATH"` as yourself and set PATH to the appropriate subset of that in your cron job.